# Can't run pulseaudio, system is mute

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio

I installed Lubuntu yesterday and just noticed I don't have any sound output. Also, there is no widget for volume control in the taskbar and when I try to add it, nothing happens. I tried to run Pulseaudio, but nothing happened either. When I tried to run it from terminal, I got the following error:

```
pulseaudio: error while loading shared libraries: libopus.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to look up what is libopus.so.0, but couldn't find it anywhere. Someone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep libopus` any output?

Comment: @guiverc I'm using version 22.04.1 LTS. Downloaded the ISO from [link](https://lubuntu.me/downloads/). 

@nobody When running this command, I get the following output: 

`ii libopus0:amd64                  1.3.1-0.1build2                    amd64            Opus codec runtime library`

Comment: Please reinstall the package. I think the missing library is a softlink. I am on mobile and cannot check. And log your user out.

Comment: @nobody how do I do that? Sorry, I've only used linux for a week before, don't really know this OS very well yet

Comment: I believe @nobody was suggesting `sudo apt install --reinstall libopus0` which would cause it be (downloaded if *deb* isn't available on your system &) re-installed..   The logout suggestion was to ensure your GUI (graphical user interface or LXQt) was aware of the change; ie. logout & login before re-testing...   *Consequences of this re-install are just that the system will note the package as manually installed; you could revert that with additional `apt-mark` but that is optional thus why @nobody likely didn't mention*

Comment: @guiverc I did that, and now the volume widget showed up, but when I try to run pulseaudio I get this:
`GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken`

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (*not comments; they're from others to the Original Poster or you; this is a Q&A site & not a forum*); as it's easier for everyone to read (*I'm busy elsewhere so others maybe able to help faster*), but also details as to your hardware may also help.. eg. a `sudo lshw -C sound` on my system (ie. *list-hardware of class sound; sudo to elevate privileges for accurate details*) tells me my hardware is handled by `driver=snd_hda_intel` the snd_hda_intel kernel module (*common name for kernel module is driver*); showing how linux detects your hardware

Comment: When the applet is showing up pulseaudio should runnung. `ps aux | grep pulse`